# RedBean как правильно обновить запись

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Всем привет, в общем не получается обновить запись. Первый файл создает таблицу с нужными строками.

```
        $user = R::dispense('users');
        $user->login = $data['login'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        $user->name = $data['name'];
        $user->family = $data['family'];
        $user->search1 = $data['search1'];
```

search1 та самая строка которая будет меняться в зависимости от того что напишет туда пользователь.
Файл номер 2

```
    $data = $_POST;
    if(isset($data['do_searchs'])) {
    $errors = array();
    if (trim($data['searchs']) == '') {

        $errors[] = "Введите номер";
    }
    if(mb_strlen($data['searchs']) < 8 || mb_strlen($data['searchs']) > 8) {

        $errors[] = "Недопустимая длина номера";

    }
    if(R::count('users', "searchs = ?", array($data['searchs'])) > 0) {
    

        $errors[] = "Такой номер существует!";
    }

    if(empty($errors)) {
        $user = R::load('users', id);
        // Обращаемся к свойству объекта и назначаем ему новое значение
        $user->search1 = ['do_searchs'];
            R::store($user);
}
}
```

И собственно вопрос, как узнать тот самый id пользователя, и как правильно указать новое значение?

Comment: $user->search1 = ['do_searchs']; Сюда не надо добавить $data?

Comment: точно мой косяк. Вот итоговый вариант, и все равно не работает.
$user = R::load('users', 'login');
$user->search1 = $data['do_searchs'];

Comment: все работает, проблема была в том что в базе все строки типа VARCHAR создались а строка search1  тип tinyint + UNSIGNED и 3 символа макс. Вручную изменил на варчар и все работает) Почему оно сразу не сделало варчар? И да строку search1 пользователь сначала не заполняет - она сразу идет пустая.